# C++11 gcc: explicit qualification in declaration? Standard ref?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

When the following C++11 program is compiled with gcc 4.7:

```
extern int i;
int ::i;

int main()
{
}
```

gcc complains that:

```
error: explicit qualification in declaration of `i`
```

Is this non-conformant behaviour?  Where in the standard is this program deemed ill-formed?

8.3p1 seems to indicate that it should be allowed:

> If the
>   qualifier is the global :: scope resolution operator, the declarator-id refers to a name declared in the global
>   namespace scope.

**Update:**

From N3485 8.3p1:

> A list of declarators appears after an optional (Clause 7) decl-specifier-seq (7.1). Each declarator contains
>   exactly one declarator-id; it names the identifier that is declared. An unqualified-id occurring in a declarator-
>   id shall be a simple identifier except for the declaration of some special functions (12.3, 12.4, 13.5) and for the
>   declaration of template specializations or partial specializations (14.7). When the declarator-id is qualified,
>   the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualifier
>   refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace (7.3.1))
>   or to a specialization thereof; the member shall not merely have been introduced by a using-declaration
>   in the scope of the class or namespace nominated by the nested-name-specifier of the declarator-id. The
>   nested-name-specifier of a qualified declarator-id shall not begin with a decltype-specifier. [ Note: If the
>   qualifier is the global :: scope resolution operator, the declarator-id refers to a name declared in the global
>   namespace scope. — end note ] The optional attribute-specifier-seq following a declarator-id appertains to
>   the entity that is declared.

Answer (score 12):

And the very next sentence says (in n3337):

> A **declarator-id shall not be qualiﬁed** except for the deﬁnition of a member function or static data member outside of its
>   class, the deﬁnition or explicit instantiation of a function or variable member of a namespace outside of its
>   namespace, or the deﬁnition of an explicit specialization outside of its namespace, or the declaration of a
>   friend function that is a member of another class or namespace.

A definition of a global variable is not mentioned among the exceptions.

Comment: What document version are you using?  I'm looking at N3485

Comment: @user1131467 n3337. I'll check n3690, too, give me a second.

Comment: The text in n3690 is the same as in your question. I find it less clear that in n3337. This sentence: *When the declarator-id is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or **namespace** to which the qualifier refers* is a little ambiguous about what "namespace" refers to. I'd say it doesn't include global namespace, because standard lingo usualy refers to it as "global scope". So I think the rule hasn't changed.

Comment: In any case, the text from n3337 is the closest to the official standard - It's safe to say the code in question is illegal *at the moment*. :)

Comment: No, it does apply to members of the global namespace, there is a note explictly clarifying this: If the
qualifier is the global :: scope resolution operator, the declarator-id refers to a name declared in the global
namespace scope.

Comment: There is a normative phrase in the standard that explicitly defines that the global namespace is a namespace.  Hence the note is only informative.  "members of a namespace" include "members of the global namespace".

Comment: @user: N3690 is the final committee draft for C++14, not C++11. There are huge number of changes in there. The latest version of the standard that can be viewed mostly as "C++11 with bugfixes" is N3485.

Answer (score 4):

GCC is right according to C++11. In C++14, this will be allowed. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#482

Comment: Weird that 482 was proposed in 2004 and didn't make it in until Nov 12.

Comment: Weird that this still isn't possible in the latest versions of clang and gcc