# How do I implement a C++ header file that doesn't contain a class name?

Tags: c++, function, methods, header-files

**EDIT: Thanks! I'm coming from Java, so it turns out I was just unfamiliar with what free functions are and how they work. I appreciate everyone's answers.**

For an assignment, I was given a C++ header file (.h) with a bunch of empty functions that I need to implement in a separate .cpp file without altering the original header fild. However, there's no explicit class or class name ever mentioned in the header file - I was expecting there to be something like

```
    ClassName 
    {
       ... functions, etc...
    }
```

but there's nothing, just the member functions. There's also no constructor.

Because there's no class or class name, I'm unsure what syntax to use to implement the member functions in the .cpp file. Where usually I would put something like

```
    returnType ClassName::functionName()
    {
        ...implementation...
    }
```

**I'm not sure what to insert in place of the ClassName, since there is no class, or if I need to use a different format entirely.** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are not being asked to implement namespace level functions?  Please include a sample of the header file.

Comment: It's hard to say, the description is not very clear for me. But it sounds like the header has a series of free functions. These are functions not associated with any class. This may be surprising to someone coming from object oriented languages like Java. To implement then, you simply omit `ClassName` in the definition. If the function belongs to a namespace, use the namespace instead of the class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is not as object-oriented as Java or C# and allows free functions - ones that exists outside of any class. It seems that your header declares exactly that.

Use simply

```
returnType functionName() //defines a function in current namespace, global or other
{
    ...implementation...
}
```

Comment: Your first example of `::` being in the global namespace is (partially) incorrect. If `returnType` is a class type, C++ will parse this as a scope resolution off of `returnType` rather than the global namespace, and this will be a [parse error](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/87xc5h). If `returnType` is a builtin type, then this parses correctly. This would also work if it were using `auto` with trailing return-type

Comment: Agree - confusing to recommend using that syntax here. I've never even used it myself.

Comment: Actually I take back about it parsing correctly at all. `clang` issues a warning, but `gcc` unconditionally errors for the explicit qualification: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qbarMG. I'm starting to question whether this is even valid syntax, or an extension

Comment: @Human-Compiler Fixed, but I don't really understand why this isn't valid if returnType is not class type. Gotta go back to standard I guess.

Comment: @Human-Compiler [It should be valid](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.qual#7). Are you not just in a `-Werror` mode? GCC's error is identical to Clang's _warning_

Comment: Check the above godbolt link; that's GCC's behavior by default. It's not a `Werror=<some warning>`, it's actually just an explicit error. Might be a bug in that case

Comment: Oh, [here we go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17958535/4386278). It's "extra" and "extra" is not permitted. Don't know why Clang is only warning.

Comment: [Seems the rule has changed over time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979242/4386278) (go figure)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I guess `clang` supports it as an extension -- TIL. Good find!

Comment: @Human-Compiler I think GCC is out-of-date in not permitting it since C++14. But, to be quite honest, I've largely given up trying to track all these tiny changes in the language. It's boring. :P

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to insert class name, you just need to correctly wrote the declared function signature in header file:

#### file.h

```cpp
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

void f ();
void g ();

#endif
```

#### file.cpp

```cpp
#include "file.h"

void f ()
{

}

void g ()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, there's no explicit class or class name ever mentioned in the header file

That's okay; not everything needs to be in a class.

And, if you were under the impression that a header is only for declarations of class-related things (because some courses tend to name them after classes whose definition they contain), that is not true! A header can contain declarations of anything! A class, multiple classes, non-class things, a mix of the above…

> there's nothing, just the member functions.

They're not member functions; they're just… functions.

> There's also no constructor.

That's okay, too! Only classes need constructors.

> Because there's no class or class name, I'm unsure what syntax to use to implement the member functions in the .cpp file.

Functions are simply defined thus:

```
int foo(…)
{
   /* code */
}
```

…where `int` is the return type, `foo` is the name, and `…` is my placeholder for your arguments (if applicable).

That's it!

There should be a chapter in your textbook about so-called "free functions", probably *before* classes.